# rails 4: active record associations: how to list all tasks from a project?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, rails-activerecord, model-associations

I have a created a demoapp, where users can have many projects, and each projects can have many tasks.

When I am logged in as a user, and visit project_path, all available and related projects to this user are listed.

But now, how can I list all tasks related to a project, from this user?

this is how I create demoapp:

```
rails g scaffold Project name:string user_id:integer task_id:integer
rails g scaffold Task name:string project_id:integer
rake db:migrate
```

**[app/models/user.rb]**

```
has_many :projects
has_many :tasks, through: :project
```

**[app/models/project.rb]**

```
belongs_to :user
has_many   :tasks
```

**[app/models/task.rb]**

```
belongs_to :project
```

**[db/seeds.rb]**

```
user = User.create! email: 'user@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password'
project = Project.create! name: 'project 1 @user', user_id: user.id
task = Task.create! name: 'task 1 @project 1 @user', project_id: project.id

user = User.create! email: 'admin@example.com', password: 'password', password_confirmation: 'password'
project = Project.create! name: 'project 1 @admin', user_id: user.id
task = Task.create! name: 'task 1 @project 1 @admin', project_id: project.id
task = Task.create! name: 'task 2 @project 1 @admin', project_id: project.id
```

and run rake

```
rake db:reset
```

finally I add devise authorization

**[projects_controller.rb]**

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
# replace all Project with current_user.projects
```

**[tasks_controller.rb]**

```
before_action :authenticate_user!
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your routes file, put something like this:

```
  resources :projects do
    resources :tasks
  end
```

That will give you a route (among others) that looks like this:

```
project_tasks_path(project_id)
```

Which equates to:

```
/projects/:project_id/tasks
```

That route will give you all the tasks associated with that particular project. Of course, you still need to set up your controller to get the tasks from the database like:

```
@tasks = Project.find(params[:project_id]).tasks
```

Comment: I see the point with resources :-) - I will try again. Thanks

Comment: Of course, you don't need to setup the routes. If you want the list of a project's tasks, just use this code in any controller you want: `@tasks = Project.find(project_id).tasks` (where project_id is any id you want/need). It might not be the "rails way", but it still works.

Comment: new problem: now I can click to a project and get the list of all tasks related to this project. But: when I try to add a new task I got the error message undefined method `tasks_path'
imho the resource path looks ok...

http://activerecord-01.dev/projects/1/tasks/new

Comment: You need to put `new_project_task_path(project_id)` for a new task associated with the project with id of `project_id`.

Comment: now: I got ``undefined local variable or method `project_id'``

Comment: In your controller, which variable are you assigning the project to?

Comment: [tasks_controller]
 ```def index
   @tasks = Project.find(params[:project_id]).tasks.all
   respond_with(@tasks)
  end
 def new
   @task = Project.find(params[:project_id]).tasks.new
  respond_with(@task)
  end
  def create
    @task = Project.find(params[:project_id]).tasks.new(task_params)
    @task.save
    respond_with(@task)
  end
  def update
    @task.update(task_params)
    respond_with(@task)  end
 private
   def set_task
     @task = Project.find(params[:project_id]).tasks.find(params[:id])
   end
   def task_params
    params.require(:task).permit(:name, :project_id)
  end
end```

Comment: Ok, I see. Change `new_project_task_path(project_id)` to `new_project_task_path(params[:project_id])` and you should be good.

Comment: still same problem. :-(

Comment: What is the path (url) of the page you are getting the error?

Comment: http://localhost:3000/projects/1/tasks -> then I click to the new task link http://localhost:3000/projects/1/tasks/new

Comment: Ok, instead of `project_id` try just `id`. That is all I can tell you.